# TLS Handshake error after server hello Done

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, tls1.2

I have a python app is connecting to a java app, both use the same certificate. This certificate is also imported in trusted-certs of both sides.

The functionality of the whole TLS handshake process was validated with a self-signed certificate.

However when I want to use a globally CA-signed certificate instead, encounter a handshake error:

This is the SSL log I got by enabling `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` on the server-side (java app):

```
.
.
.
***
update handshake state: certificate[11]
upcoming handshake states: server_key_exchange[12](optional)
upcoming handshake states: certificate_request[13](optional)
upcoming handshake states: server_hello_done[14]
upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  public y coord: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
update handshake state: server_key_exchange[12]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_request[13](optional)
upcoming handshake states: server_hello_done[14]
upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
*** ServerHelloDone
update handshake state: server_hello_done[14]
upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
Thread-54, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 2075
Thread-54, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
Thread-54, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, unknown_ca
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
%% Invalidated:  [Session-4, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
Thread-54, called closeSocket()
Thread-54, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
```

The last lines, aftrer **ServerHelloDone**, indicate the error:

```
Thread-54, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 2075
Thread-54, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
Thread-54, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, unknown_ca
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
%% Invalidated:  [Session-4, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
Thread-54, called closeSocket()
Thread-54, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
```

The next step is apparently **client_key_exchange**. Is it related to the client's private key in any way?

What does `unknown_ca` mean? Is the certificate missing in the client's trust_cert or in server's?

The below image is also the traffic that was captured using Wireshark, primary lines are using the self-signed certificate, and **the last 3 lines** are for the troubled certificate, discussed above:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> What does unknown_ca mean? Is the certificate missing in the client's trust_cert or in server's?

`unknown_ca` means that the certificate is not trusted due to a missing CA in the trust store. Since the alert is sent by the client it means that the client does not trust the CA which issued the servers certificate. This might be because the root CA is missing in the trust store but it might also be that the server did not send the necessary intermediate certificates so that the client could build the trust chain to the local root CA.

Comment: Thank Steffen. Even though I now added the CA issuer's certificate to the client trust store, still get the same handshake error. Regarding the intermediate certificate on the server, I'm not sure what it could be, I just added the Ca issuer's certificate belong the server certificate on server side too. in the following link, are steps I have taken including contents of the cert files in each step, so you might see what exactly is going wrong. It's here: (It would be more legible in a markdown viewer) https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wfxcDGrJpH . Thank you

Comment: @DummyBeginner: Unfortunately it is impossible to say based on this what you are really doing and what effect this has, i.e. it might be that you've added it in the wrong trust store, that you've added the wrong certificate, that intermediate certificates are still missing etc. There is practically nothing known about your code and certificate and setup which might make it possible to reproduce your exact problem and thus point out what exactly is done wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the following up Steffen. The two assumptions you stated: `it might be that you've added it in the wrong trust store, that you've added the wrong certificate` apparently couldn't be the case, As I already tested a **self-signed** certificate in the same trust store and it worked correctly inside the app and code.

Comment: However, about `...that intermediate certificates are still missing`, I'm suspicious of that too; Because As I pointed out in the link in my first comment above, I just have the server certificate and acquired its CA issuer certificate via the URL in its AIA extension, So if the latter would be the root certificate, and the first one would be the server certificate, Where could I obtain the intermediate certificate? And then import that in the single certificate which currently only contains root and server certificates?

Comment: @DummyBeginner: Usually the CA which issues the certificate gives you all necessary certificates. As to how to make sure that your application uses all these - this depends on the specifics of your application how this is done. You cannot put multiple certificates into a single certificates but server applications should be able to load leaf certificates and chain certificates and serve all of these to the client. But again - nothing to reproduce here and no details shown so a more focused help would be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info Steffen

Comment: Do we need to add the full chain in the trust store ? Thanks

Comment: @DiegoRamos: Usually the server has to send the full chain and the client only has the root CA in the trust store.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks a lot Steffen